# Float item in list

Tags: html, css

I have problem, I don't know how to solve, it's difficult to explain but I will try, there is also picture to demonstrate.

I've problem with  ordering list, when next row of li item goes on second row there is a lot of space between above row and under row, I would to be without spacing.

https://jsfiddle.net/52suh3pt/

- I've tried to solve with float:left but it's working only for one side.

Look this picture, left is correctly and that I want, right is currently.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
<li><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252_960_720.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-background_1344-24.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt=""></li>
<li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
  width:835px;
}
li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style:none;
  width:262px;
}
img{
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Try https://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is relatively easy to achieve with [Masonry](https://masonry.desandro.com/).

Masonry does not requires jQuery, it works as a standalone library. The best part is that you can initialize it with HTML. The minifeid library size is about 24Kb. The number is reduced to slightly under 8kb if you use [Gzip compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)

The steps are simple.

1. Load the library using

   ```
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js></script>
   ```
2. Find the grid wrapper `div` and use it to initialize the masonry or in my
   example.

   ```
   <div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".item"}'>
   ```
3. Add [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to make items responsive based on your
   personal preference.

**Working responsive example:**

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 3px;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media (min-width: 0px) {
  .item {
    width: 99%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
  .item {
    width: 49%
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .item {
    width: 32.33%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 2160px) {
  .item {
    width: 24%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>


<div class="grid" data-masonry='{ "itemSelector": ".item"}'>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252_960_720.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-background_1344-24.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg">
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg">
  </div>

</div>
```

This can be further improved by using the [imagesLoaded](https://imagesloaded.desandro.com/) library to make sure masonry doesn't trigger until all the photos have fully loaded. This helps prevent broken layout. However, I won't go into that as that's beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```css
div {
  width: 835px;
}

.col {
  width: 30%; 
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}


img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="col">
    <li><img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/04/15/04/02/water-1330252_960_720.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/blue-background_1344-24.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt="">
    </li>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <li><img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MpDQSvxf9s0/VWXlWnzC3NI/AAAAAAAAF-c/HlZS-DDyosg/w1200-h630-p-k-no-nu/fundo-vermelho%2B%25281%2529.jpg" alt=""></li>
    <li><img src="http://images.all-free-download.com/images/graphiclarge/free_swirly_blue_stars_vector_background_148475.jpg" alt=""></li>
  </div>

</div>
```